# Возможность утечки памяти из многомерного массива

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
private final byte[][][] array;
...
for(int i = 0; i < array[value].length; i++)
  array[value][i] = null;
array[value] = null;
```

В массивах обьектов можно было бы просто поставить *null* к нужному элементу, чтобы память со временем освободилась, как дела обстоят с примитивами?

UPD: мы не можем выбросить весь массив, нам нужно очистить только его часть.

Comment: даже без null память будет освобождаться, т.к. в java есть клёвая штука, которая уничтожает всё на своём пути. GC называется

Comment: Спасибо КО. GC не может уничтожить обьекты на которые есть активная ссылка. Приведу простой пример утечки памятив java (я думаю он всем знаком): мы создаем массив и пытаемся сделать его resize, если в нем есть элементы, то без принудительных null'ов элементов старого массива память утечет (т.е. старый массив никогда не будет собран GC).

Answer (score 2):

Какие глупости. Не надо никакие `null`'ы туда выставлять. Выбросьте просто весь массив целиком (`array = null` или `array = anotherArray`) и всё будет собрано. Выставление `null`'ов туда — пустой расход ресурсов процессора, а сборщику мусора это ничем не поможет. Все элементы, массивы, массивы массивов будут признаны как недостижимые (в ходе анализа достижимости) и будут уничтожены, когда придёт время.

> > GC не может уничтожить объекты на которые есть активная ссылка. Приведу простой пример утечки памяти в java (я думаю он всем знаком): мы создаём массив и пытаемся сделать его *resize*, если в нем есть элементы, то без принудительных `null`'ов элементов старого массива память утечёт (т.е. элементы старого массива никогда не будут собраны GC, даже если на них нет внешних активных ссылок).

Нет, такой случай никому не знаком :) Это — нонсенс, и был бы страшный позор для любого сборщика мусора. Если активная ссылка идёт от объекта (`A` ссылается на `B`), на который нет ссылок (на `A` никто не ссылается), то это его ссылка ни на что не влияет, они оба будут выброшены.

UPD: если не нужно уничтожать весь массив, то просто занулите более ненужный под-массив или ненужные элементы.

UPD2: мне подумалось ещё вот что: а вы уверены, что вам действительно нужен этот трёхмерный массив? Управлять им сложно... особенно, если размерности меняются на ходу. Если это какая-то *sparse*-матрица, то, возможно, вам стоит подумать о других формах её хранения.

UPD3: прочтите про работу сборщика мусора в Java и не будет тогда никаких странных предположений о возможных побочных эффектах. Сборщик мусора Java не считает ссылки — он выполняет анализ достижимости. Вкратце, принцип такой: если до объекта нельзя добраться от статического контекста или работающих потоков, то это значит, что этот объект — мусор и должен быть уничтожен. И не важно, ссылаются ли части мусора друг на друга или нет. Прочтите хотя бы статью в википедии про сборщики мусора: [Сборщики мусора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

**UPD4: Итак, финальное обобщение ответа**: *утечки памяти в Java (в классическом их понимании) невозможны. Однако, возможно истощение ресурсов из-за логической ошибки в приложении. Например, часто причиной являются разного рода кэши и `HashMap`'ы. Всякая мистика вроде ссылок со "старых" объектов на какие-то другие — это всё из разряда народной молвы. Просто забудьте про всю эту чепуху и сконцентрируйтесь на деле. Например на том, что работать с трёхмерным массивом сложно. Следует четырежды думать, прежде чем делать двумерный массив, и восемь раз прежде чем делать трёхмерный. Однако, если вы всё же уверены в его НЕОБХОДИМОСТИ, то смело выкиньте первый цикл из вашего кода.*

Comment: Где-то видел плохой пример реализации стека на java, сейчас не могу найти ссылку, но приведу часть кода:
<pre><code>Object[] newArray = new Object[_array.lenght+10];
System.arraycopy(_array, 0, newArray, 0, array.lenght);
_array = newArray;</code></pre>
По идее у нас утекают элементы старого массива, т.е. если мы обнулим ссылку на старый элемент в новом массиве, то элемент не будет собран (или как-то так).
<a href="http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp01246/index.html">Задержание обьектов</a>

Comment: Ничего они никуда не утекают и если мы обнулим ссылки в новом массивы, то элементы будут выброшены. К тому же, старый массив сам может быть собран в тот же миг, как только мы сделали присвоение _array = newArray

Comment: «в тот же миг» — ну, насколько я имею представление о Джаве, это не вполне правда, поскольку Джава не Питон и её сборщик работает исключительно по таймеру.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что если в этот момент запустится сборка, то она разберётся. По поводу таймера: это не обязательно. Всё зависит от того, какой сборщик выбран. Он может вообще ничего не собирать, пока памяти хватает для аллокации.